# Android Intent problems

Tags: android, android-intent

I'm having an issue trying to go to a specific class within my android application using the Intent.

This is my code setup:

```
Intent Secondscreenintent = new Intent(this, Secondscreen.class);
```

The error that it gives me is

```
android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {/project10.aventus.quiz.Secondscreen}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
```

After looking at my manifest I could not see any mistakes that would indicate this message.

```
<activity
    android:name=".Main"
    android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
    android:label="Quiz">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>

<activity
    android:name=".Secondscreen"
    android:label="Secondscreen" />
<activity
android:name=".Quizclass"
android:label="Quizclass"/>
```

These are within the  tag within the  tag.

But somehow I'm still getting the class not found error. I have even tried to refer the intent to the Main.class and this has given the same error that it cannot find the Main class.

Does anyone have an idea on how to fix this?

Thanks,
Shams.

Comment: Nothing else in the StackTrace, no NullPointerException? All Activities are in the same `project10.aventus.quiz` package, declared in the `AndroidManifest.xml` file?

Comment: Try this android:name="<package Name>.Secondscreen"

i.e : android:name="com.example.Secondscreen"

Comment: your Secondscreen.class not declared in manifest file,please add the activity.

Comment: @shkschneider Yes they are in the same package. Hovering over them shows me the detail of its location and they are identical.

Comment: @Palak I have tried your suggestion and it has not resulted in a success.

Comment: @prakash You can see in my Manifest xml that the activities are declared.

Comment: please add the package name with the activity name,`android:name="packagename.Secondscreen"`.that's best way to declared the class

Answer (score 1):

In you `AndroidManifest.xml` you will find some thing like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   package="project10.aventus.quiz"
   android:versionCode="1"
   android:versionName="your_version_code">
   ...
</manifest>
```

**package** defines the root of your implementation. So you don't have to write the full path name if you define Activities, BroadCastReceiver etc...

So you do it in this way:

```
<activity
    android:name=".Secondscreen"
    android:label="Secondscreen" />
```

This entry means - you will find my Secondscreen.java in my root folder aka `package`. In your case it would be `project10.aventus.quiz`.

So i quess your Secondscreen.java is not there. I'm creating allways a new subpackage `ui` in my root folder, so my activity entry looks like this:

```
 <activity
       android:name=".ui.Secondscreen"
       android:label="@string/second_screen"
       android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
 </activity>
```

Now, this entry means - you will find my Secondscreen.java here: `project10.aventus.quiz.ui.Secondscreen.java`